# MATLAB: Filter struct based on column value

Tags: matlab

i'm new to matlab, too used to python and having difficulty finding a way to filter a struct similar to how i can filter a pandas dataframe in python based on condition.

**Matlab**

```
a = arrayfun(@(x) x.value ==10, Data);
Data_10 = Data(a);
```

> Error using arrayfun Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output
>   1. Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

**How i would do so in python:**

```
Data_10 = Data[Data.value == 10]
```

Comment: Why do you need arrayfun? Does `Data_10 = Data(Data.value == 10)` not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data_10 = zeros(size(Data.value));
Data_10(Data.value==10) == 10;
```

This should write into your array Data_10 the value 10 into each position, that has a 10 in Data and leave the rest as 0.

I am not sure if I fully understood your question. Here is my underestanding:

You want to filter certain values of an matrix.

Lets imagine we have a Matrix A filled with values. You want to filter values smaller than lowthresh = 0 and greater than upthresh = 5.

```
A = [3 6 -2.4 1; 0 34 4.76 0.5; 84 3 2.32 4; 1 -1 2 3.99];
lowthresh = 0;
upthresh = 5;
A(A<lowthresh | A>upthresh) = NaN; % Nan is a good flag
```

Output:

```
A =

    3.0000       NaN       NaN    1.0000
         0       NaN    4.7600    0.5000
       NaN    3.0000    2.3200    4.0000
    1.0000       NaN    2.0000    3.9900
```

Having substituted your values you can do some basic functions ignoring NaNs:

For instance average:

```
mean(A,'omitnan')

ans =

    1.3333    3.0000    3.0267    2.3725
```

I hope this adresses your question. Notice, that you can do this for any statement, that returns a boolean (isnan(), ... ) even if the boolean does not have anything to do with the matrix at all.

Lets say we have 2 matrizes that have the same size but different numbers:

```
A =

     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     0     0

B =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

We can easily say:

```
B(A==1) = 2

B =

     2     2     0
     2     2     0
     0     0     0
```

I hope it helped a bit,

cheers Pablo